# PC with HDMI connecting to TV with VGA, has signal but TV displays "Not Supported"

Tags: hdmi, vga, tv

I want to play shows from my laptop on my TV. My laptop has a HDMI port and TV has a VGA port. I used this [adapter](https://www.amazon.com.au/gp/product/B00SW9JI9A) & a VGA cable to link my laptop and Philips TV. When I link up the devices, the TV error message changes from "No Signal!" to "Not Supported!". I've scoured the internet for solutions with no luck, does anyone have suggestions here?

Comment: You need to provide more details, such as how this HDMI interface is configured (and the alternatives), and the capabilities of the VGA port on the TV.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the resolution you're outputting to the TV isn't supported.  Try and change the resolution (if you can) and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: And the refresh rate too. The computer doesn't know what the TV supports - only what the adapter supports.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed the refresh rate and now it works:))